# What should be the regex pattern for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, logging

I want to extract only this whole part - **"value":["10|8.0|1665|82|apple|#||0","8|1132|188.60|banana|#||0"]** from all the lines in a text file and then write into another text file. This part have different values in every line.

I have written this regex pattern but unable to get these whole part in another text file.

```
with open("result.txt", "w+") as result_file:
     with open("log.txt", "r") as log-file:
         for lines in log-file:
            all_values= re.findall(r'("value"+:"[\w\.#|-]+")', lines)
            for i in all_values:
                result_file.write(i)
```

Comment: Short question: is the value of value a list of values or is that just an example of what a value of value can be?

Comment: do you mean like `"value":\[".*?"]` ? https://regex101.com/r/lcL0zM/1 or adding the missing chars to the character class `"value":\["[\w\.#|",-]+"]` https://regex101.com/r/KSyID7/1

Comment: yes, its the list of values @ThomasKlinger

Comment: "value":\[".*?"] - this worked, Thanks. @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern, you can omit the outer parenthesis for the capture group to get a match only.

This part `"+` matches 1 or more times a double quote which does not seem to be required.

You don't get the whole match, because there are more characters in the string than listed in the character class `[\w\.#|-]+`

As a more broader match, you can use

```
"value":\[".*?"]
```

- `"value":` match literally
- `\["` Match `["`
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possible
- `"]` Match `"]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lcL0zM/1)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this explanation, more understandable now.